# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in NODEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to programming and taking up javascript. I'm trying to output the result of the request on the console but it keeps throwing off errors. I'm watching from a video and it works fine on tutor's part. What am I doing wrong? Please bail me.
NB: Not real key

```
request({
   url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Lagos+Nigeria&key=AIzaSyCGv0HDQB2dhHl6mY29PwqXAavIK3U',
   JSON: true
}, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(`Address: ${body.results[0].formatted_addresss}`);
    console.log(`Latitude: ${body.results[0].geometry.location.lat}`);
    console.log(body.results[address_components]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try change argument "body" to "response"

```
request({
   url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Lagos+Nigeria&key=AIzaSyCGv0HDQB2dhHl6mY29PwqXAavIK3U',
   JSON: true
}, (error, response, body) => {
console.log(`Address: ${response.results[0].formatted_addresss}`);
console.log(`Latitude: ${response.results[0].geometry.location.lat}`);
});
```

maybe you have nothing inside

Comment: Googleapi works fine. Its outputs Results, address, geometry, Latitude, Longitude etc. I want to be able to request these and have it output on console

Comment: try change argument "body" to "response"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably correct, but it's not "save".

Your specific problem is, that the API Key you specify as the `key`-parameter is not valid. If you paste the URL into your Browser and hit enter, you'll see the following response:

```
{
   "error_message" : "The provided API key is invalid.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

My guess is, that you copied the API key from the tutors video. In this case, it might be invalid now. You should [request your own key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key) and try again.

---

About the **unsave** code part: Your code falsely assumes that the request will always return the data you expect. In this case, it doesn't (because there was an error). The received data does not look like your program expects it to, so it crashes.

To avoid this and have a more specific error-message, check if the result actually looks like you expect. For example:

```
(error, response, body) => {
  if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300) {
    // HTTP Status code indicates success
    if (body.status === "OK") {
      console.log(`Address: ${body.results[0].formatted_addresss}`);
      console.log(`Latitude: ${body.results[0].geometry.location.lat}`);
      console.log(body.results[address_components]);
    } else {
      // API-specific error. Check documentation for more info
    }
  } else {
    // The request was successful but the server responded with an error. Handle it!
  }
};
```

The documentation for the API will tell you what to expect in the `status`-field and how to handle the different cases.

Comment: I took out a few letters in the key as I presume its supposed to be private to me(more like password). However, key works fine and gives information from URL. I only want to be able to request that information into console. From the suggested code above, it shows that error is thrown from API-specific error.

Comment: @SodiqHighdIdowu Ok, next time you should mention that in your question. Also, add the output you're getting to your question please.